# Are gfortan whole array expressions, enabled?

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, gfortran

I'm new to fortran and to gfortran. I learned that whole expression arrays are calculated in parallel, but I see that calculations only take place in just one core of my computer.

I use the following code:

```
program prueba_matrices

 implicit none

 integer, parameter                             :: num = 5000
 double precision, dimension(1:num,1:num)       :: A, B, C
 double precision, dimension (num*num)          :: temp
 integer                               :: i

 temp = (/ (i/2.0, i=1,num*num) /)
 A = reshape(temp, (/ num, num/) )
 B = reshape(temp, (/ num, num/) )
 C = matmul(A , B)

end program prueba_matrices
```

I complie like this:

```
gfortran prueba_matrices.f03 -o prueba_gfortran
```

And, watching the graphs produced in real time by gnome-system-monitor, I can see that there is only one core working. If I substitute the line with the calculation

```
  C = matmul(A , B)
```

for

```
  C = A * B
```

It yields the same behaviour.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: I think that he is just testing the parallelization of arrays and not the mathematics...

Comment: Where did you see that statement that gfortran executes whole array expressions in parallel?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark : Yes, I know the two sentences are not the same. As KyleKanos says, I'm just testing the parallelization.

Comment: @M.S.B : The referred statementet is in [this fortran course](http://www.liv.ac.uk/HPC/HTMLF90Course/HTMLF90CourseNotesnode124.html#SECTION000146000000000000000)

Answer (score 2):

GFortran/GCC does have *some* automatic parallelization features, see http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/AutoParInGCC . They are frequently not that good, so they are not enabled at any of the -ON optimization levels, you have to select it specifically with -ftree-parallelize-loops=N, where N is the number of threads you want to use. Note however that in your example above a loop like "A*B" is likely constrainet by memory bandwidth (for sufficiently large arrays), and thus adding cores might not help that much. Furthermore, the MATMUL intrinsic leads to an implementation in the gfortran runtime library, which is not compiled with the autopar options (unless you have specifically built it that way).

What could help your example code above more is to actually enable any optimization at all. With -O3 Gfortran automatically enables vectorization, which can be seen as a way to parallelize loops as well, although not over several cpu cores.

Comment: Note that `-ftree-parallelize-loops=N` is for parallelizing **loops**, which the OP has only 1. This likely will not help for `matmul(A,B)`.

Comment: @KyleKanos: Indeed, I thought that my sentence about the MATMUL implementation being a library routine made that point already, although perhaps implicitly.

Comment: I guess my point was that the program will be spending a lot more time on the `matmul` part of the code than the loop part (dropping 5000-->1500 and no compilation options, I get 0.05 sec for the loop and 5 sec for `matmul` calculation!). Whatever time is going to be saved in the loop parallelization is going to be completely irrelevant for the whole code above.

Comment: Now that I think about it: I suppose the OP was wanting to see if AutoPar of vectors/arrays was true or not. If his intention is to use the knowledge in multiple loops, your suggestion is 100% correct. For this problem, it's nearly useless.

Comment: Excuse me, but ... what is "OP"? (I'm not very familiar with this jargon, but hope I learn it).

Comment: @janneb , Thank you very much for your answer, but I tried your propose and the behaviour doesn't change: only one core is still used. I used `gfortran -O3 -ftree-parallelize-loops=3 prueba_matrices.f03 -o prueba_gfortran_3 ' and also tried whit 2,4,5,6 and just one core is still used by all of them.

Comment: So, Isn't ther a way to parallelize these calculations. The real use I will make of, is not to multiply, but to subtract two conformant matrices. Then, I'll use a LAPACK routine to calculate eigenvectors. So it would be nice to make LAPACK work using parallelization capabilities. Any suggestion?. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that I also need to parallelize a long loop. Thanks again.

Comment: Use something like OpenMP or MPI to explicitly parallelize. For LAPACK, there exists implementations that internally use multiple threads. MKL, or plain lapack with ATLAS, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your call to matmult from gfortran to be multithreaded, easiest is to simply link to external [BLAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) package that has been compiled with multithreading support.  Candidates include [OpenBlas](http://xianyi.github.io/OpenBLAS/) (née Goto Blas), [ATLAS](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net), or commercial packages like Intel's [MKL](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl), AMD's [ACML](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/cpu-development/amd-core-math-library-acml/), or Apple's accelerate framework.

So for instance, for this simple example:

```
program timematmult

  real, allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: A, B, C
  integer, parameter :: N = 2048

  allocate( A(N,N) )
  allocate( B(N,N) )
  allocate( C(N,N) )

  call random_seed
  call random_number(A)
  call random_number(B)

  C = matmul(A,B)

  print *, C(1,1)

  deallocate(C)
  deallocate(B)
  deallocate(A)

end program timematmult
```

With the base matmul:

```
$ gfortran -o matmult matmult.f90
$ time ./matmult
   514.38751

real    0m6.518s
user    0m6.374s
sys     0m0.021s
```

and with the multithreaded gotoblas library:

```
$ gfortran -o matmult matmult.f90 -fexternal-blas -lgoto2
$ time ./matmult
   514.38696

real    0m0.564s
user    0m2.202s
sys     0m0.964s
```

Note in particular here that the real time is less than the user time, indicating multiple cores are being used.

Comment: Thank you, I have to try this.

Comment: Hi, my compiler doesn't find the goto2 library. Which package should I install (I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: I understand now that the library in question is in the external BLAS package. And it is external because it is not installed by the package manager, but compiled by myself. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a key sentence in the course that you cited is "With array assignment there is no implied order of the individual assignments, they are performed, conceptually, in parallel."  The key word is "**conceptually**".  It isn't saying that whole array expressions are actually executed in parallel; you shouldn't expect more than one core to be used.   For that, you need to use OpenMP or MPI (outside of Fortran itself) or the coarrays of Fortran 2008.

EDIT: Fortran didn't have, as part of the language, actual parallel execution until the coarrays of Fortran 2008.  Some compilers might provide parallelization otherwise and some language features make it easier for compilers to implement parallel execution (optionally).  The sentence that I cited from the web article better states reality than the portion you cite.  Whole-array expressions were not intended to require parallel execution; they are a syntactical convenience to the programmer, making the language higher level, so that array operations can be expressed in single statements, without writing do loops.  In any case, no article on the web is definitive.  Your observation of the lack of parallel executions shows which statement is correct.  It does not contradict the Fortran language.

Comment: Yes, but it says: ` The above assignment is equivalent to:

!PARALLEL
    B(-4,0) = C(1,1)*D(0,0)-B(-4,0)**2 ! in ||
    B(-3,0) = C(2,1)*D(1,0)-B(-3,0)**2 ! in ||
     ...
    B(-4,1) = C(1,2)*D(0,1)-B(-4,1)**2 ! in ||
     ...
    B(0,2)  = C(5,3)*D(4,2)-B(0,2)**2  ! in ||
!END PARALLEL `